# Core 2 Duo Macbook OS 10.6.8 to OS 10.7.5

Tags: macos

I am running 10.6.8, on a  2.1 13" white-2008 Intel Core 2 Duo Macbook
Am I able to upgrade to OS X 10.7.5 "Lion & is it free or $20

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update to 10.7.5 - I'm running it on my older (2006) white MacBook. You will have to [purchase it through Apple for $20 here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion).

Answer (score 0):

if you want download officialy from mac app store you need call to apple they will give you a code by this you will able download from mac app store or you can download somewhere in internet from torrent. if you want install 10.7